# Ubuntu 14.04 will not connect to NFS v4 server

Tags: networking, mount, nfs

Our small LAN is running an NFS v4 file server. We have several clients running Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. We have one client running Ubuntu 14.04. The 14.04 client will not connect to the file server. The others all connect fine. The settings are the same on all clients. And all clients are listed in /etc/exports on the server.

Is there a known issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and NFS v4 servers?

journalctl on the server does not shown any NFS related errors.

The 14.04 client can ping the fileserver as well as log in via SSH. The user name / ID as well as group match. (I'm using the same user account / uid on both client and server. It is uid 1000.)

I have reviewed all the seemingly relevant NFS questions on StackExchange that I found.

My questions are:

1. What are the next troubleshooting steps?
2. How can I use systemd / journalctl (or anything else) to find more detailed error information?

$ sudo mount -a

```
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting fileserver:/export/path/one
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting fileserver:/export/path/two
```

$ ping fileserver

```
PING fileserver (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fileserver (192.168.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.310 ms
```

$ ssh fileserver

```
Last login: Tue Aug 16 14:38:26 2016 from 192.168.1.2
[me@fileserver ~]$
```

$ showmount -e fileserver

```
Export list for fileserver:
/export/path/one/ 192.168.1.2
/export/path/two/ 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3
```

$ rpcinfo -p fileserver

```
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  58344  status
100024    1   tcp  58561  status
100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
```

$ sudo mount -vvv -t nfs4 fileserver:/export/path/one /path/one/

```
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: spec:  "fileserver:/export/path/one"
mount: node:  "/path/one/"
mount: types: "nfs4"
mount: opts:  "(null)"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs4"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "fileserver:/export/path/one"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/path/one/"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw"
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Tue Aug 16 16:10:43 2016
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.2'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting fileserver:/export/path/one
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 when connecting to an NFS v4 fileserver  which is running the latest upstream packages. And Ubuntu 14.04 is supposed to be supported currently.

Comment: What are the `/etc/exports` declarations on the server?